# Fast way to compute the fibonacci numbers

Tags: algorithm, performance, matrix-multiplication, fibonacci

If I will use the following method to compute Fibonacci numbers it will be faster than a linear method:

[image]

Am I right?

The method is from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number).

Comment: (Do you think matrix multiplication non-linear? On a RAM, it will be *slower* due to result growing "super-linearly" faster than argument.)

Comment: If you need all Fibonacci numbers up to a certain one, just remember the last two values to calculate the next (simple addition). Matrix multiplication would be far too much work. If you only need a certain Fibonacci number, use the so called [fast doubling](https://www.nayuki.io/page/fast-fibonacci-algorithms) method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Formula:

[image]

Using an [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) you'll get an `O(log(n))` multiplications to find n-th Fibonacci number. But the multiplication is not a trivial operation in this case and the actual time complexity is `O(M(n)*log(n))` where `M(n)` is a complexity of multiplication of two numbers with length `O(n)`.

There is a [benchmark](https://www.nayuki.io/page/fast-fibonacci-algorithms) of several algorithms computing Fibonacci numbers including matrix approach with naive multiplication and Karatsuba multiplication.

Comment: Could you, please check out my implementation? [Here](https://gist.github.com/oobarbazanoo/2de7a1f8082b86d33147ae2c81fa9724) it is.

Comment: @trafalgarLaww, I've checked only `operator^`. Computations seem to be ok, but it's weird that this operator changes the object itself. Also, there is no need to multiply the matrix by the vector at the end.

Comment: Thank you very much for the attention.

Answer (score 0):

There's also a direct formula - Fibonacci's sequence is a linear recurrence relation and there's a known exact formula for the n-th element. The formula is:

[image: fibonacci formula]

where phi is the [golden ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio) and psi is its inverse.

As with the matrix approach this can be computed in `O(log(n))` multiplications.
There's the drawback of phi being a floating point number so you might get errors from rounding for large numbers.

P.S. I happen to have written [a blog post on the problem](http://dimitroff.bg/linear-recurrence-relations-or-how-to-solve-recursive-sequences-effectively/). You can also take a look at what [wikipedia has to say about it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression).

Comment: This is impractical

Comment: @Sopel Why would it be impractical?

Comment: Because it implies floating-point errors. Arbitrary precision floats are more complicated than bigints. It's hard to estimate the precision needed to compute it for given value.

Comment: @Sopel: It is not hard to estimate the precision needed. Fibonacci numbers are integers, so computing the value with accuracy less than ½ and then rounding to an integer suffices. In fact, we do not need the psi^n term at all; computing phi^n/sqrt(5) within, say, 1/4 of the exact result and rounding to an integer suffices, except for the first two terms.

Comment: So how many mantissa and exponent bits do you need to compute (not store) F(123456)?

Comment: @Sopel: 86,000 significand bits suffice. (This could be refined, but you referred to an estimate.) The lowest bit needed in the final result is in the integer position, so the exponent, as a power of two, only needs to be around 86,000, so 17 bits suffice for the upside. The fractions involved in portions of the calculation will not be small (will have a leading bit not much below the integer position), so one more suffices for a signed exponent.

Comment: @Sopel: By the way, when you respond to comments, please use “@<username>” to ensure the person you are addressing is alerted.

Comment: @EricPostpischil by that reasoning you could compute up to F(76) with IEEE double precision floats, but F(72) is already wrong.

Comment: @Sopel: That’s not my reasoning; I left plenty of room in the significand for digits beyond those needed for the final answer, to allow for rounding errors and additional precision needed in intermediate calculations. Note that log2 of F(123456) is about 85,707, but I estimated 86,000 bits.